# Using Group By in Java 8 with Property

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, collectors

```
package com;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class GroupByDemoInJava8 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();  // Date Format is MM/DD/YYYY
        people.add(new Person("John", "London", 21 , "2/1/18"));
        people.add(new Person("Swann", "London", 21 , "3/5/18" ));
        people.add(new Person("Kevin", "London", 23 , "3/12/18"));
        people.add(new Person("Monobo", "Tokyo", 23 , "4/18/18"));
        people.add(new Person("Sam", "Paris", 23 , "7/12/18"));
        people.add(new Person("Nadal", "Paris", 31, "4/2/19")); 
        Map<String,List<Person>> personByCity = new HashMap<>(); 

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");


        personByCity = people.stream() .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(sdf.parse(Person::getDateOfBirth))); 


         for (Map.Entry<String,List<Person>> entry : personByCity.entrySet()) { 
                System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey());
                System.out.println("Value = " + entry.getValue());
        } 

    }
}


class Person
{ 
    private String name; 
    private String city; private int age; private String dateOfBirth;

    public String getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(String dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public Person(String name, String city, int age , String dateOfBirth) 
    { 
        this.name = name; this.city = city; this.age = age;this.dateOfBirth=dateOfBirth;
    }

    public String getName()
    { return name; } 
    public void setName(String name) 
    { this.name = name; } 
    public String getCity() 
    { return city; } 
    public void setCity(String city)
    { this.city = city; } public int getAge() { return age; } public void setAge(int age) { this.age = age; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [name=" + name + ", city=" + city + ", age=" + age + "]";
    }
}
```

**Unfortunately, I get the following compilation error**

> - The method parse(String) in the type DateFormat is not applicable for the arguments   (Person::getDateOfBirth)
> - The target type of this expression must be a functional interface

Comment: The name of variable personByCity is wrong, suggesting a grouping by city. But that's of course not the solution. I'll check it at the office.

Comment: I've never seen storing a date as a string either converting it every time you're fetching it. Try converting it in the construction time and storing it as a date. Then fetch it as a date. That should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you say the dates are in the format MM/DD/YYYY, but in fact they are not. Your data should be defined:

```
List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>(); // Date Format is MM/DD/YYYY
people.add(new Person("John", "London", 21, "02/01/2018"));
people.add(new Person("Swann", "London", 21, "03/05/2018"));
people.add(new Person("Kevin", "London", 23, "03/12/2018"));
people.add(new Person("Monobo", "Tokyo", 23, "04/18/2018"));
people.add(new Person("Sam", "Paris", 23, "07/12/2018"));
people.add(new Person("Nadal", "Paris", 31, "04/02/2019"));
```

Secondly do not use `SimpleDateFormat` it is long outdated, use [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) and [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)from java 1.8 instead:

```
Map<LocalDate, List<Person>> personByCity = new HashMap<>();
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
personByCity = people.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> LocalDate.parse(p.getDateOfBirth(), dtf)));
```

Comment: Thank you it works  can we sort using date ?? , expecting the lowest date should be displayed first

Comment: Consider upvoting/accepting the answer in that case. Can you please be more specific - On what basis do you want to sort the date?

Answer (score 4):

Method reference operator is used to replace the lambda expression if it is a direct method call, But in your case you are trying to do `groupingBy` based on the result of `sdf.parse`

[Method References](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)

> You use lambda expressions to create anonymous methods. **Sometimes, however, a lambda expression does nothing but call an existing method. In those cases, it's often clearer to refer to the existing method by name.** Method references enable you to do this; they are compact, easy-to-read lambda expressions for methods that already have a name.

And also `parse` method from [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-) throws `ParseException` were you need to handle it, in addition to that it returns `java.util.Date` so you need to change return type to `Map<Date,List<Person>>`

```
public Date parse(String source) throws ParseException
```

Still if you wanna use `SimpleDateFormat` you need to handle the exception

```
 Map<Date,List<Person>> personByCity = people.stream() 
                      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(person->{
                          try {
                             return sdf.parse(person.getDateOfBirth());
                           }
                           catch(ParseException ex){
                                //log error
                              }
                            return new Date();
                         });
```

The recommended approach i prefer is use `LocalDate` by using `DateTimeFormatter`

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yy");

 Map<LocalDate,List<Person>> personByCity = people.stream() 
                      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(person->LocalDate.parse(person.getDateOfBirth(),formatter));
```

**Note** Your input date string `"2/1/18"` and format pattern `"MM/dd/yy"` both are valid but the return type will be changed based on the implementation, below is the example

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yy");

LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("02/01/18", formatter);

System.out.println(date);      //2018-02-01

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");

Date d = sdf.parse("02/01/18");

System.out.println(d);       //Thu Feb 01 00:00:00 CST 2018
```

Comment: person.getDateOfBirth() is the object which does not contain the person object methods.

Comment: Thank you for the time , can i sort the data based on the date property in ascending order